# Date null pointer exception because of format not matching ? Java

Tags: java, date

I have a `HashMap<Long, Date> forecastedEndDates`. It is in a field class named `Card`.
In my `JUnit test` I want to `assertEquals` my Date and a Date from the map, but
 on

`date1 = card.getForecastedEndDates().get(95L);`

line, it givens me a null pointer exception. I have declared and initialized the date as:

`Date date1 = new Date()`

I can't go and change Date to Calendar or Time, because it is too big of a project.
I have a suspicion that there is a format mismatch. When I `println` `Date.getTime()`, I get `1538473954932` and when I do:

`Card card = new Card();
card.getForecastedEndDates().get(95L);`

I get: `Tue Oct 16 03:16:34 EEST 2018`

I fill in the map with:

```
Map<Long, Date> forecastedEndDates = new HashMap<Long, Date>();
    forecastedEndDates.put(50L,
         Date.from(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
             .plus(Math.round(forecast.getSimulation().getMedian() * DAY_IN_MILISECONDS), ChronoUnit.MILLIS)
             .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
```

The 50L is the key and the Date is value

Comment: Is it just me sensing a contradiction here? First you say that `card.getForecastedEndDates().get(95L)` throws a `NullPointerException`, next you say it yields `Tue Oct 16 03:16:34 EEST 2018`. It can’t do both, at least not on the same call.

Comment: Strange: In the test, you use the key 95L, in your code snippet to set the values you use 50L.